# What is wrong with my vector declaration in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble declaring a vector of class objects. The class I'm trying to reference is in a header file and its constructor calls for an array of 6 strings.

```
string Data[6];
vector<Gamer> fileOut;

void split(string input)
{
    stringstream ss(input);
    int count = 0;

    while (ss.good()) {
        string substr;
        getline(ss, substr, ' ');
        Data[count] = substr;
        count++;
    }
}

void readGamerfile()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("gamers.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        split(line);

        fileOut.push_back(new Gamer(Data));
    }
}
```

Above is my code and I'm not sure why when I declare the variable `fileOut` I get an error saying:

```
identifier "gamer" is undefined
```

I'm using visual studio code and I'm not really sure whats going on because I believe it should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please copy and paste error message, don't paraphrase it. If it is already copied and pasted, please provide [mcve], as there is nothing called `gamer` in your code.

Comment: Before you can do `vector<Gamer> fileOut;`, you need to make sure `Gamer` is known in the file.

Comment: The loop in `split` should have the same structure as the loop in `readGamerfile`.

Comment: There is no `gamer` symbol in code (note case). Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your vector is declared as follows

```
vector<Gamer> fileOut;
```

you do not need `new` here

```
fileOut.push_back(Gamer(Data));
```

or even

```
fileOut.emplace_back(Data);
```

Also make sure you include whatever header is required for the definition of `Gamer`

```
#include "Gamer.h"
```

Answer (score -3):

If Gamer is a structure the declaration should be `vector<struct Gamer>` or if it is an object then `vector<className>`.

Comment: There is no difference in the treatment of `struct` and `class` in this context. That `struct` is only noise.